# How to derive Church-Kleene ordinal

Tags: set-theory, computability, ordinals

Crossing-out: (How does one prove the existence of Church-Kleene ordinal? Also, why is it labeled as $\omega_1^{CK}$?

And why is it first ordinal not hyperarithmetical, and is the first admissible ordinal after $\omega$?)

Edit: OK, I will cross out the first question and the second question. And I will change my question to this:

How does one prove that $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is the model of Kripke-Platek set theory, and how does one prove that it is first admissible ordinal after $\omega$? (So why can't $\omega+1$ can be a model of KP set theory?) And why is it first ordinal not to be hyperarithmetical?

And somehow extraneous question: Why are admissible sets labeled "admissible"? Curiosity.

Comment: $\omega_1^\text{CK}$ is the supremum of the computable ordinals. The supremum of a set of ordinals always exist. In ordinary set theory, $\omega_1$ denote the supremum of the set of countable ordinals. $\omega_1^{CK}$ is analogous notation for the computable ordinals.

Comment: Also what does admissible mean? An exercise on page 157 of Sack's $\textit{Higher Recursion Theory}$ states that $\omega_1^\text{CK}$ is the first $\Sigma_1$ admissible ordinal after $\omega$.

Comment: @William: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_ordinal

Comment: @William Changed my question.

Comment: Heh. You changed the second question... to the second question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila By "second question" I meant the part about labeling. But anyway. Is there something not answerable about my question?

Comment: Ah. So you changed the question from the question about the particular notation as to the actual definition. Yeah, that is a change. As for not being answerable, not at all. I am just not familiar enough with the caveats of computability and admissible ordinals to answer this question (in comparison, I know enough about relative constructibility).

Comment: Admissible sets were introduced by Kripke. $\omega + 1$ isn't admissible because it's not closed under $\Sigma_1$ replacement. In fact it should be fairly obvious that admissible ordinals must be limit ordinals. The rest follows from the recursiveness of ordinals below $\omega_1^{CK}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let me elaborate on the last paragraph of Boris' answer above.

Define $\omega_1^{CK}$ (as usual) as the least noncomputable ordinal - that is, the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that no computable well-ordering of the natural numbers has ordertype $\alpha$. You ask:

> Why is $\omega_1^{CK}$ the first non-hyperarithmetic ordinal?

Well, certainly every computable ordinal is hyperarithmetic, so this really boils down to: why is $\omega_1^{CK}$ non-hyperarithmetic (precisely: why is there no hyperarithmetic relation on the natural numbers with ordertype $\omega_1^{CK}$)? This is an important theorem of Spector: in general, a structure can have a hyperarithmetic copy without having a computable copy, but for ordinals we have "hyperarithmetic = computable" *(Incidentally, this result was later [strengthened by Montalban](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27588367))*.

There are a couple different ways to prove Spector's theorem. Sacks' book has what I think is the standard proof. A different proof *(which I cooked up myself, but I think is probably folklore)* is to show how, given a hyperarithmetic (even $\Sigma^1_1$) ordinal $\alpha$, there is a computable ordinal $\beta$ with $\beta>\alpha$; this then implies that $\alpha$ itself has a computable copy (just "chop off" a computable copy of $\beta$ at the appropriate point). Constructing such a $\beta$ takes a bit of an argument, but it's self-contained and doesn't invoke [Kleene notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O).

---

Specifically, here's how we construct such a $\beta$. *(I'm assuming here that we've already proved "hyperarithmetic = $\Delta^1_1$" - if not, see Sacks' book. It's worth noting that this too can be proved without invoking notations at all, if we define "hyperarithmetic" as "computable from the jump sequence along some computable well-ordering.")* Suppose $\alpha$ is a hyperarithmetic ordinal. Fix a $\Sigma^1_1$ formula $\varphi(x, y)$ defining a well-ordering $\mathcal{W}$ on a ($\Sigma^1_1$) subset of $\omega$ with ordertype $\alpha$. By the normal form theorem for $\Sigma^1_1$ sentences, $\varphi(x, y)$ can be assumed to have the form "The tree $S_{x, y}$ has an infinite path" for some uniformly computable family of trees $(S_{a, b})_{a, b\in\mathbb{N}}$ on $\omega$. *(WLOG suppose $\alpha$ is infinite.)*

Associated to $\varphi$ is a **tree of approximations**, $T_\varphi$. A node $\sigma$ on $T_\varphi$ is a triple $(m, F, (p_{(a, b)})_{(a, b)\in F})$ consisting of:

- A natural number, $m$ *(the "length" of the node)*.
- A finite set $F$ of pairs of natural numbers, intended to represent part of $\mathcal{W}$.
- For each pair $(a,b)\in F$, a finite path $p_{(a, b)}$ of length $m$ in the tree $S_{a, b}$. *(Remember, this tree has an infinite path iff $a<_\mathcal{W}b$.)*

The ordering on $T_\varphi$ is defined by setting $$(m, F, (p_{(a, b)})_{(a, b)\in F})<(n, G, (q_{(a, b)})_{(a, b)\in G})$$ iff

- $m<n$,
- $F\subseteq G$, and
- For each $(a, b)\in F$, we have $p_{(a, b)}\prec q_{(a, b)}$.

By the usual coding shenanigans, this tree can be thought of as a computable subtree of $\omega^{<\omega}$.

This tree is **not well-founded**: in particular, it has infinite paths corresponding to the actual structure of $\mathcal{W}$ (and sub-relations). However, attached to each node $\sigma\in T_\varphi$ is a finite linear order - namely, the "$F$" part. These "amalgamate" as we move up the tree (this is the requirement $F\subsetneq G$ in the definition of the ordering above), and - since any infinite path corresponds to a subrelation of $\mathcal{W}$ - we have that *the direct limit along any path is well-founded*.

Form a tree of descending sequences through that direct limit (it's a bit messy to write this down, but it's fine); this tree is computable and well-founded. Taking its [Kleene-Brouwer ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%E2%80%93Brouwer_order) gives a computable well-ordering of ordertype $\ge\alpha$.

*(This argument can be generalized to prove a stronger result, [which was what I actually needed when I cooked it up (Theorem 1.4)](https://docs.google.com/a/wisc.edu/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=d2lzYy5lZHV8c2Nod2ViZXJ8Z3g6MmQyNDE0MmRmNzA4NjJkMA).)*

---

Arno Pauly [has also given (corollary 81)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00386) a proof of Spector's theorem using the machinery of admissible representations, but I haven't read it in detail yet so I don't know how different it is.

Answer (score 1):

An ordinal $\alpha$ is admissible if $L_\alpha\models\Sigma_0$-collection. Here, for any set theory $T$, $M\models T$ means that for any set $S$, if $S\in M$ then all $S'\in M$ for all $\phi(S)\vdash S'$ if $\phi$ is a formula on sets that $T$ either assumes or proves to exist (the formula not the sets; trying to avoid double meanings). $\Sigma_0$-collection is an assumption that if $\phi$ is a formula with parameters in $N$ for some $N$, then there exists a set $X:=\{S|\phi(S)\}$.

$\omega$ is the first admissible ordinal because $L_\omega$ is the set of all finite sets in the constructible hierarchy, where "finite" means that it has finite length and all elements of it are also finite. Clearly if $S_{1,...,n}$ is a sequence of finite sets, then $\{S_1,...,S_n\}$ is also finite, therefore $L_\omega$ is the minimal model which satisfies "if $S_{1,...,n}$ are in $L_\omega$, then $\{S_1,...,S_n\}$ is also in $L_\omega$".

The same cannot be said about $L_{\omega+1}$ because, among other things, $L_\omega\in L_{\omega+1}$ and $L_\omega$ is an infinite set, so $L_{\omega+1}$ doesn't satisfy finite set grouping axiom, and neither does it satisfy any other form of collection.

$\omega^{CK}_1$ is the least ordinal above $\omega$ such that $L_{\omega^{CK}_1}\models\Sigma_0$-collection, since for any *computable/recursive* well-order $\langle\mathbb{X},\prec\rangle$ on sets $X\subseteq\mathbb{X}$, if $\mathbb{X}\in L_{\omega^{CK}_1}$ then $\text{field}(\prec)\in L_{\omega^{CK}_1}$. The same follows for all $\omega^{CK}_{\alpha+1}$ except that we have well-orders restricted to $\langle\mathbb{X},\prec\rangle\cong\langle\beta,<\rangle$ for some $\omega^{CK}_\alpha\leq\beta\in\omega^{CK}_{\alpha+1}$, which is why admissibles are ususally not limits of admissibles, aka in the form $\omega^{CK}_\alpha$ for a limit $\alpha$. I am saying "usually", because the ones that *are* admissibles as well as limits of admissibles are called *recursively inaccessible* ordinals.

$\omega^{CK}_1$ is the first non-hyperarithmetical ordinal, because it is the least unrecursive well-ordering of $\omega$. The recursive well orderings are those of the form of $\Delta^1_1$-defineable (aka hyperarithmetic) subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: The reason I say it is true for theories with PTO of $>\psi(\varepsilon_{\Omega+1})$ is because I am certain this holds for all such theories, but not certain if it holds for all theories in general. Probably not.

Comment: The last claim is false. There are theories with high PTOs which have $L_\omega$ as a model. What would be true if you restricted attention to theories extending KP (most considered set theories do).

Comment: You are right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Your last paragraph requires proof ...

Comment: +Noah Schweber What paragraph? The one about hyperarithmeitcal subsets? That follows from definition, but if you want a source I can link you a paper mentioning it.

Comment: It doesn't follow directly from the definitions. It's not true that recursive well-orders are precisely the hyperarithmetic ones. However, what is true that any hyperarithmetic well-order _is isomorphic to_ a recursive well-order, so the notion of a recursive ordinal and hyperarithmetical ordinal coincide. It is a nontrivial fact and does require a proof; Noah's answer gives some details.

Comment: Why are recursive well-orderings the $\Delta_1^1$-definable ones instead of the $\Sigma^0_1$-definable relations that are well-orderings?

Comment: I'm also not sure the description of $\vDash$ here is correct - there are countable $\beta$ such that $L_\beta\vDash\textrm{KP+}``\omega_1\textrm{ exists}"$, even though $\omega_1$ is not a member of $L_\beta$.

Comment: $\omega_1$ is indeed not in any countably tall (or even of height $\omega_1$) models of $KP+\exists\omega_1$ of the form $L_\beta$, but the point is that every $(KP+\exists\omega_1)$-provable statement with parameters from $L_\beta$ holds in $L_\beta$. Also, the meaning of $\omega_1$ and any cardinal notion changes depending on the model.

Comment: For example, from the perspective of $L_\beta$ we have $\beta=Ord$ and if $L$ is thin, then there are some countable ordinals that, from the perspective of $L$, have most large cardinal properties consistent with $V=L$, such as being $\alpha$-iterable, remarkable, $(\omega,\alpha)$-Ramsey and so on.